# How to implement a interface in TypeScript that attr is ()?

Tags: typescript

I just saw Vue3 reactive lib code simply. However, I'm not familiar with TypeScript. I don't know how to implement the interface like below:

```js
export interface ReactiveEffect<T = any> {
  (): T
  _isEffect: true
  id: number
}
```

I think that `():T` means a function return type T. If I declare an interface like below:

```js
interface a {
  (): string,
}
```

I can implement it successful like:

```js
let b: a;
b = ():string => 'b';
```

But I want to know how to implement an interface that attrs contains `()` and other like `ReactiveEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript function is an object, so it can have properties:

```js
function ReactiveEffectImpl() {}

ReactiveEffectImpl._isEffect = true;
ReactiveEffectImpl.id = id();
```

Comment: yes, that is right. I know your meaning. But I don't know how to write with TypeScript Language. like: ReactiveEffectImpl implments ReactiveEffect.

Comment: @uuz exactly like that :) . An interface that has a call signature (ie has a `()`) can only be implemented by a function. A function declaration can have fields added without explicit declarations as above. While  `ReactiveEffectImpl` does not explicitly implement `ReactiveEffect` is does implement it structurally, so `ReactiveEffectImpl` will be assigable to `ReactiveEffect`

Comment: @uuz once you assign properties to function is type change to include it. So once you assign this function to `ReactiveEffect` it typechecks.
 [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWBxgQDdgBRddYbGAHgBU4BeOTJATwD44BvAFBw4ACgCUALjiMhcAPoIAzlRp0pMKAFdgshABMpSTQFsARmgEBfAQPSakdBBCRx0Scf1lRgMTVBcAjFY2bgB0CsrUtPBsGtrsinDYzoowANy2SKH6rHAADBkCyUipcMBRagREjuQq0fRGZmi8bG6FQA)

Comment: @АлексейМартинкевич Thanks! I undertood. Great Explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type for your function definition

```
type func = ()=>string

interface some{
  a:string
  b:func
  c:number
}

let a:some = {a:"hi", c:6, b:()=>"hello"}
```